# Descending list in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How do I get the a name of a list of the content of a folder in descending order in PS?

- I just want to get a name of folders of a path.

I am using `Get-ChildItem`, but I don't know how to go any further.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following command:

```
gci  c:\YOUR_PATH | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime -Descending | select -Property Name | foreach { $_.Name }
```

**gci** is the short version of Get-ChildItem

**$_.PSIsContainer** will filter the folders available in the current context.

**sort CreationTime -Descending** will sort descending the content of the output.

**Select -Property Name** Will select the property "Name."

**foreach { $_.Name }** will process item per item.

For more help please use the **Get-Help** cmdlet.

Comment: I've corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: You can shorten this to `gci  c:\YOUR_PATH -Dir | sort CreationTime -Desc | select Name`.